# Is it possible to create an editable app with an ArcGIS Online Public Account?

Tags: editing, arcgis-online

I have been experimenting with creating apps from templates in an ArcGIS Online **Public** Account. While I can create apps that let me view my web map, I have yet to find a way to create a map that works with the edit tools in the app templates.

My web map has one shapefile that was loaded into the map as a zip file. When I try to configure the Find, Edit, Filter or GeoForm templates from this web map, it tells me there isn't an editable layer to work with even though I have editing enabled.

I suspect the problem lies with the way my shapefile has been uploaded. Is there a way to upload a shapefile that will let me edit it in the app? Loading it as a zipped shapefile or geodatabase doesn't work. Should I try to publish it from ArcGIS for Desktop? Is there a way to do this with a public account? Or is it just not possible unless I upgrade to an organizational account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, uploading a shapefiles inside a web map will not provide an editable layer, since no feature service gets created in the process.  Instead, you get a static layer stored with the web map.  From the [ArcGIS Online Help](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm) (emphasis mine):

> If you have a small amount of data in a shapefile—generally fewer than 1,000 features—you can make it available for others **to view** through a web browser by adding it as a .zip file containing the .shp, .shx, .dbf, and .prj files to a map you create with the map viewer.
>
> When you add a shapefile, the map viewer converts it to a format that web clients can quickly read and display.

To create a feature service within ArcGIS Online, you need a organizational account (i.e. paid subscription).  Again from [ArcGIS Online Help](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/hosted-web-layers.htm) (emphasis mine):

> You must have the following to publish layers to ArcGIS Online:
>
> - **An account that is part of an ArcGIS Online organization**
> - Privileges to create content and publish hosted web layers
> - ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop or a later release (if you want to publish hosted web layers from ArcMap)

Answer (score 3):

To add to eric's answer, the shapefile needs to be served up as a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online.

Depending on your use-case, perhaps get a [Developer Account](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/plans/) (still free, 50 credits a month) where you can achieve your goals.  Just check the small print on what you can do with it before doing anything commercially.  If your doing this at your organisation, get a ArcGIS for Organisation free trial - does not take much to prove the business value with ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Good point Simon!  I forgot about Developer Account as an option.

Comment: I just checked out the Developer account link, and it looks like they are no longer free? Or is there a well hidden Free version somewhere still? Thank you!